# Is it possible to automatically export many subsequent frames in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, animation

I am using inkscape to make a small series of scenes and then am stitching them together using R. I was wondering if there is a way to track movement and automatically export many frames from inkscape? Or if there is an easier way to do this? I am quite new to this, so any suggestions would be very welcome. :)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Inskcape isn't animation software and doesn't have any of these features. Maybe have a look at open source animation software such as Blender or Synfig Studio instead.